Problem with Bevel in edit mode

When applying the first bevel in edit mode, I apply weight = 1 to only the top two verticles (clamp overlap is turned off), then add volume with soildify, and finally, in edit mode, apply the three bevels excluding the bottom edge. Bevel was applied to the edge by giving weight = 1 (clamp overlap was turned off). However, errors continue to occur in the beveled part like that. I don't know the cause.
